# Using LASSO for Only Variable Selection

Tags: r, feature-selection, lasso, glmnet

How valid is an approach of using LASSO to determine appropriate values to then use in a logistic regression that does not use any penalties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using lasso for feature selection, followed by a non-regularized regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213077/using-lasso-for-feature-selection-followed-by-a-non-regularized-regression)

Comment: It does. Thank you @RyanFrost